# Python Grouping within a List

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working with a text file and I've pulled out the information I'm interested via findall. This data is then being presented to me in either a string such as this:

```
user1 : null 
user2 : Joe Bob 
user3 : Sandra Sandy 
user4 : John Doe
user5 : Joe Bob 
user6 : John Doe 
user7 : John Doe
```

Or a list such as:

```
['user1 : null, user2 : Joe Bob , user3 : Sandra Sandy, user4 : John Doe, user5 : Joe Bob, user6 : John Doe, user7 : John Doe']
```

I would like to loop through these and group them together based on the second column such as:

```
John Doe : user4, user6, user7
Joe Bob: user5, user2
null: user1
Sandra Sandy: user3
```

The end goal is to be able to pull out the "owner" variable such as John Doe and create a ticket saying he has these users.

The code below uniques the managers in my list and parses through my user_manager_str and groups them accordingly but I still don't have a good way to break them out so I can create unique tickets per manager.

```
# Get a unique list of managers
for i in manager:
    if i not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(i)

for i in unique_list:
    uniq_manager = i
    #print(uniq_manager)
    for line in user_manager_str.split('\n'):
        if uniq_manager in line:
            #print('Creating SN ticket for ' + uniq_manager)
            print('SN content is: ' + line)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict 

s = """user1 : null 
user2 : Joe Bob 
user3 : Sandra Sandy 
user4 : John Doe
user5 : Joe Bob 
user6 : John Doe 
user7 : John Doe"""

result = defaultdict(list)
for line in s.splitlines():                        #Iterate each line
    line = line.strip().split(":")                 #Split string by ":"
    result[line[1].strip()].append(line[0].strip())  #Create key-value

for k, v in result.items():
    print(k, ":", ",".join(v))
```

**Output:**

```
 null : user1 
 Joe Bob : user2 ,user5 
 Sandra Sandy : user3 
 John Doe : user4 ,user6 ,user7
```

Comment: Thank you very much. While all of the solutions worked, I feel like this is the easiest to read for other people looking at the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with `pandas` library you'll get much flexibility with less lines (when working with tabular data):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """user1 : null
user2 : Joe Bob 
user3 : Sandra Sandy 
user4 : John Doe
user5 : Joe Bob 
user6 : John Doe 
user7 : John Doe"""


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\s+:\s+', engine='python', header=None, keep_default_na=False)
for i, v in df.groupby(1).agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x)).iterrows():
    print(i, ': ', ', '.join(v))
```

The output:

```
Joe Bob :  user2, user5
John Doe :  user4, user6, user7
Sandra Sandy :  user3
null :  user1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re` and `itertools.groupby`:

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

data = '''user1 : null
user2 : Joe Bob
user3 : Sandra Sandy
user4 : John Doe
user5 : Joe Bob
user6 : John Doe
user7 : John Doe'''

for v, g in groupby(sorted(re.findall(r'(.*?)\s*:\s*(.*)', data), key=lambda k: k[1]), lambda k: k[1]):
    print('{}: '.format(v) + ', '.join(i[0] for i in g))
```

Prints:

```
Joe Bob: user2, user5
John Doe: user4, user6, user7
Sandra Sandy: user3
null: user1
```